# インストール後、native-platform.dllのロードに失敗するエラーが発生します

Tags: gradle

Gradleをインストール後にパスを通しコマンドプロンプトでバージョン確認のコマンドを実行した際に下記のようなエラーメッセージが現れました。
このエラーについてネットで調べてみてもほとんど情報が出てこなかったので、解決方法をご存じの方がおられましたら、お力をお貸しいただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Windows 7 32bit
Gradle 2.13

```
C:\>gradle -version

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 7 x86.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

Comment: GradleとWindowsのバージョン(32bit or 64bit)を追記したほうが良いかもしれません。また、こちらの現象と同じような感じでしょうか？ http://stackoverflow.com/q/36429504/4366193

Comment: エラーが発生しない環境なのでわかりませんが、`Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll'`なので、`%UserProfile%\.gradle`ディレクトリ配下(?)に当該ファイルが存在するか確認してみたほうが良いかもしれません。 参考:http://hiroba.main.jp/studio/2016/04/15/1-5-1to2-0/

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
Windowsは32bit,Gradleは2.13になります。
リンク先のものとはエラーメッセージの詳細が異なります。
コピペしてきただけなのでエラーメッセージは最初に投稿したものですべてとなります。
native-platform.dllが読み込めないといわれているので、インストールしたファイル類を調べてみましたが、これに該当するファイルはありませんでした。

Comment: Gradle IDE Pack 3.7.x+1.0.xをインストール後もう一度同様の操作をしたところ、問題なくバージョンが表示されました。
コメントくださった方ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Gradle IDE Pack 3.7.x+1.0.xをインストール後もう一度同様の操作をしたところ、問題なくバージョンが表示されました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @nrhizm さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/25039/%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e5%be%8c-native-platform-dll%e3%81%ae%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%ab%e5%a4%b1%e6%95%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%99#comment23978_25039)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>